# What is the easiest way to add a code snippet to third party Joomla theme?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

Completely new to Joomla. Hope that what I'm asking is simple and quick.

I thought it was module (the easiest way that is). So I created it, made it to properly include required scripts and styles, made it show up only on home page. But now that it shows, it appears in a default module structure, with a title and module content container. Can't I simply inject my snippet without extra markup? Simply a div with id and a script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a System Plugin for Joomla and use the onAfterFilter event to add your script's and style's to the document.

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript("http://www.example.com/js/myscript.js");
$doc->addStyleSheet("http://www.example.com/css/mystylesheet.css");
```

A documentation on how you can create plugins can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin